# Function in array as arguments for WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I have this function hardcoded into content-single-product.php (WooCommerce) and it works to show 3 random products from **categories ID 64 and 72**:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 64, 72 ),
        ),
    ),
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
```

Now, instead of hardcoding the category ID, I added a custom field to the product `MyCustomField` and wrote **64,72** in it. Then I tried to modify the above code to be populated dynamically:

```
$MyCustomField = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'MyCustomField', true);

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( $MyCustomField ),
        ),
    ),
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly:

`'terms' => array( $MyCustomField )`

because it only displays products from the first category (ID 64), and not from both, as I want.

I'm a newbie programmer so what did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the problem is coming from `$MyCustomField` which you enter as such in:

```
'terms' => array( $MyCustomField ),
```

The query consider it as only one value: `'64,72'`, a string.

So try:

```
$MyCustomFieldValues = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', $MyCustomField ) );
```

This will also ensure your values are integers.

Then:

```
'terms' => $MyCustomFieldValues,
```

Comment: Read carefully other answers which are also interesting...

Comment: Yes, I have, and will plan to use all input, including checking for an empty custom field, as sMyles suggested. You guys have been of great help!

Answer (score 4):

From the WordPress codex:

> relation (string) - The logical relationship between each inner
>   taxonomy array when there is more than one. Possible values are 'AND',
>   'OR'. Do not use with a single inner taxonomy array.

Few other things too, you should be saving the values to the custom meta as an array, WordPress will automatically serialize that value:

Using `update_post_meta` will automatically serialize any array you pass it:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'MyCustomField', array( 64, 72 ) );
```

Then you can just unserialize it when pulling the value:

```
$MyCustomField = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MyCustomField', TRUE ) );
```

You should probably also check to make sure you have a value before making the WP_Query call

```
if( ! empty( $MyCustomField ) ){

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $MyCustomField,
            ),
        ),
    );

}
```

If your plan is to add these values through the WP Admin interface (meaning you want to input a CSV), then you should use @ClemC approach, and use `explode`, with `array_map` to convert to integers

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing in the text (string) "64,72" to a function that expects an array of integers, then you need to translate that incoming string into an integer array.  Try adding this statement before your `$args =` statement:

```
$MyCustomField = array_map('intval', explode(',', $MyCustomField));
```